# Get ul and li values in jQuery UI Sortable on drag then drop

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, html-lists

I have this code:

```
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
<li class="ui-state-default">Song Description 1</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">Song Description 2</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
<li class="ui-state-default">Song Description 3</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">Song Description 4</li>
</ul>
```

What i need to do is when i drag and drop (ex. Song Description 1 from `#sortable1` to some position in `#sortable2`) to give me an alert (ex. Song 1 from `#sortable1` was dropped in `#sortable2`)

Is that possible? Should i add ID's to the "li"'s?

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to add `id` to the sortable items, jQueryUI provides callback functions (see *Events* on http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) you can hook into when certain events occur. In the example below I am using the *receive* callback which is passed the *event* and *ui* object parameters which contain everything you need to construct the message.

#### JavaScript

```
​$('#sortable1, #sortable2').sortable({
    connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
    receive: function(event, ui) {
        console.log(ui.item.html() + ' from #' + ui.sender.context.id + ' was dropped in #' + this.id);
    }
});​
```

Also made a [**demo on jsFIddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/U67cY/)